# Title: Issue with BigInt Conversion and White Screen in React DApp Production Build

Tags: react

Problem Description:

I have developed a decentralized application (DApp) using React that interacts with a smart contract. The DApp works as intended in the development environment, but when I try to run the production build, it displays a white screen along with the following error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number
    at Math.pow (<anonymous>)
    at vi (converters.ts:40:29)
    at converters.ts:47:8
    at index.js:9:17
    at index.js:9:17
```

Context:

The DApp uses React, Web3.js, and Metamask for interacting with a smart contract.
The issue is specifically happening when trying to run the production build of the DApp. It works as expected in the development environment.
The error message suggests that there might be an issue related to converting BigInt values to numbers.

my APP.js

```
import { Button, Container, Form, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
// import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import contractABI from "./contractABI.json";
import Web3 from "web3";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [contract, setContract] = useState();
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);
  const [proposalAmount, setProposalAmount] = useState("");
  const [proposalAddress, setProposalAddress] = useState("");
  const [proposals, setProposals] = useState([]);
  const contractAddress = "0x7e1868e9Fc46f6Ec7131987f0e33C19A6593c403";

  let provider = typeof window !== "undefined" && window.ethereum;

  const connect = async () => {
    try {
      if (!provider) return alert("Please install Metamask");
      const accounts = await provider.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
      if (accounts.length) {
        setUser(accounts[0]);
        setConnected(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };

  const getContract = async () => {
    try {
      const web3 = new Web3(provider);
      const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
      setContract(contract);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProposal = async () => {
      if (contract) {
        const count = await contract.methods.proposalCount().call();
        const fetchedProposals = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
          const proposal = await contract.methods.proposals(i).call();
          fetchedProposals.push(proposal);
        }
        setProposals(fetchedProposals);
        console.log(fetchedProposals);
        console.log(count);
      }
    };

    fetchProposal();
  }, [contract]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getContract();
  }, []);

  const createProposal = async (e) => {
    try {
      const web3 = new Web3(provider);
      const amount = web3.utils.toWei(proposalAmount.toString(), "ether");
      await contract.methods
        .createProposal(amount, proposalAddress)
        .send({ from: user, value: web3.utils.toWei("10", "wei") });
      setProposalAmount(0);
      setProposalAddress("");
      refreshProposals();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleMember = async () => {
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    // const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei("10", "wei");
    await contract.methods.becomeMember().send({
      from: user,
      value: 10,
      gasPrice: gasPrice,
    });
  };

  const handleVote = async (proposalId, vote) => {
    if (user) {
      await contract.methods
        .voteOnProposal(proposalId, vote)
        .send({ from: user });
    }
    refreshProposals();
  };

  const handleExecute = async (proposalId) => {
    await contract.methods.executeProposal(proposalId).send({
      from: user,
    });
    refreshProposals();
  };

  const refreshProposals = async () => {
    const count = await contract.methods.proposalCount().call();
    const fetchedProposals = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      const proposal = await contract.methods.proposals(i).call();
      fetchedProposals.push(proposal);
    }
    setProposals(fetchedProposals);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <h1 className="text-center">DAO</h1>
        <div className="connect-button">
          <Button onClick={() => connect()}>
            {connected ? user.slice(0, 4) + "..." + user.slice(38) : "Connect"}
          </Button>
        </div>

        <div className="create-proposal">
          <h3>Create Proposal</h3>
          <Form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default form submission behavior
              createProposal(); // Call the createProposal function directly
            }}
          >
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Amount (ETH)</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="number"
                step="0.01"
                value={proposalAmount}
                onChange={(e) => setProposalAmount(e.target.value)}
                required
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                value={proposalAddress}
                onChange={(e) => setProposalAddress(e.target.value)}
                required
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="submitbtn">
              Create proposal
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </div>

        <div className="member-button">
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => handleMember()}>
            Become A Member
          </Button>
        </div>
        <p>(Only members can create or vote on proposals)</p>
        <div className="ongoing-proposal">
          <h3>Ongoing Proposal</h3>
          <Table striped bordered hover>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Send To</th>
                <th>Total Yes Votes</th>
                <th>Total No Votes</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Executed</th>
                <th>Vote</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {proposals.map((proposal) => (
                <tr key={proposal.id}>
                  <td>{proposal.id.toString()}</td>
                  <td>{proposal.creator}</td>
                  <td>
                    {Web3.utils
                      .fromWei(proposal.amount.toString(), "ether")
                      .toString()}
                    <p>2</p>
                  </td>
                  <td>{proposal.sendTo}</td>
                  <td>{proposal.totalYesVotes.toString()}</td>
                  <td>{proposal.totalNoVotes.toString()}</td>
                  <td>
                    {new Date(Number(proposal.endTime) * 1000).toLocaleString()}
                  </td>

                  <td>{proposal.executed ? "Yes" : "No"}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Button
                      variant="success"
                      disabled={proposal.executed}
                      onClick={() => handleVote(proposal.id, true)}
                    >
                      Yes
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      variant="danger"
                      disabled={proposal.executed}
                      onClick={() => handleVote(proposal.id, false)}
                    >
                      No
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <Button
                      variant="success"
                      disabled={proposal.executed}
                      onClick={() => handleExecute(proposal.id)}
                    >
                      Execute
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </Container>
      <div class="container">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

an my smart contract code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract DAO {
    struct Proposal {
        uint256 id;
        address creator;
        uint256 amount;
        address payable sendTo;
        uint256 totalYesVotes;
        uint256 totalNoVotes;
        uint256 endTime;
        bool executed;
    }

    uint256 public proposalCount;
    mapping(address => bool) public members;
    mapping(uint256 => Proposal) public proposals;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => bool)) public voted;

    event ProposalCreated(uint256 id, uint256 amount, address payable sendTo);
    event VotedProposal(uint256 proposalId, bool vote);
    event ProposalExecuted(uint256 proposalId, uint256 amount, address payable sendTo);

    modifier onlyMember() {
        require(members[msg.sender], "Only members can call this function");
        _;
    }

    modifier proposalExists(uint256 proposalId) {
        require(proposalId > 0 && proposalId <= proposalCount, "Invalid proposal ID");
        _;
    }

    modifier proposalNotExecuted(uint256 proposalId) {
        require(!proposals[proposalId].executed, "Proposal has already been executed");
        _;
    }

    function becomeMember() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= 10 wei, "You have to send at least 10 wei");
        require(!members[msg.sender], "You are already a member");
        members[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function createProposal(uint256 amount, address payable sendTo) public payable onlyMember {
        require(msg.value >= 10 wei, "You need to send 10 wei to create a proposal");
        uint256 proposalId = proposalCount + 1;
        Proposal storage proposal = proposals[proposalId];
        proposal.id = proposalId;
        proposal.creator = msg.sender;
        proposal.amount = amount;
        proposal.sendTo = sendTo;
        proposal.endTime = block.timestamp + 2 minutes;
        proposalCount++;
        emit ProposalCreated(proposalId, amount, sendTo);
    }

    function voteOnProposal(uint256 proposalId, bool vote) public onlyMember proposalExists(proposalId) {
        require(!voted[msg.sender][proposalId], "You have already voted");
        require(proposals[proposalId].endTime >= block.timestamp, "Voting has ended for this proposal");

        voted[msg.sender][proposalId] = true;
        Proposal storage proposal = proposals[proposalId];
        if (vote) {
            proposal.totalYesVotes += 1;
        } else {
            proposal.totalNoVotes += 1;
        }
        emit VotedProposal(proposalId, vote);
    }

    function executeProposal(uint256 proposalId)
        public
        onlyMember
        proposalExists(proposalId)
        proposalNotExecuted(proposalId)
    {
        Proposal storage proposal = proposals[proposalId];
        require(proposal.endTime <= block.timestamp, "Voting for this proposal has not ended yet");
        require(proposal.totalYesVotes > proposal.totalNoVotes, "More members voted against the proposal");
        require(proposal.amount <= address(this).balance, "Contract does not have enough balance");

        proposal.executed = true;
        address payable receiver = proposal.sendTo;
        receiver.transfer(proposal.amount);

        emit ProposalExecuted(proposalId, proposal.amount, proposal.sendTo);
    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```